# mongodb: matching an element in an array and updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, updates

Basically, I have done aggregation to get the total and the list of objects that formed the total.

Now, I have to update the source table with aggregated object id for the elements that contribute to the aggregation. Basically forming relation both ways.

```js
coll.aggregate([
    { "$match": {"elig": 1, "nid" : null, "cncl" : null  } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$nkey",
        "cumqty": {"$sum": "$pr_qty.qty" },
        "netted" : { "$push" : "$_id" } 
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "nkey":"$nkey" ,
        "cumqty": "$cumqty",
        "netted" : "$netted" ,
        "_id" : 0 
    }},
    { "$out": aggcollnm }
])
```

Now, the aggregrated table has the list of obj ids formed with $push.

Say, doc1, doc2 and doc3 have formed the agg1, and agg1 has doc1, doc2 and doc3 in its list. I want the doc1, doc2 and doc3 to have agg1's id as nettid.

So I did the below

```js
coll.find().forEach( function(elem) {
    coll.update (
        { "_id" : elem._id },
        { "$set" : { nid : aggcoll.aggregate ( [
            { "$unwind" : "$netted" } ,
            { "$match" : { "netted" : elem._id } },
            { "$project" : { "_id" :1 } }
            ] )._firstBatch[0]
        }}
    )
})
```

It worked fine in a smaller set. But for 1M docs failing with the below error.

> 2014-06-30T09:48:40.577+0100 Error: getMore: cursor didn't exist on server, possible restart or timeout? at src/mongo/shell/query.js:116
>   failed to load: ./netting.js

Is there a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You are running MongoDB 2.6, so there are ways to update more efficiently as well as your generally processing seems to be in reverse. You should be looping your "aggcoll" and then updating your target from within that:

```js
var batch = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
counter = 0;

aggcoll.find().forEach(function(agg) {
    batch.find({ "_id": { "$in": agg.netted }}).update({ "$set: { "nid": agg._id } });
    counter++;

    if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
        batch.execute();
        counter = 0;
        batch = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( counter > 0 )
    batch.execute();
```

Your "inline" aggregate statement was not a very efficient way to do what you were trying and would have slowed things down a lot. Here, not only does issuing updates across all the matched `_id` values via [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as this is a "multi" update operation, but also the general use of the [bulk operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) reduces traffic to the server and time taken.

Really though, I don't know why you are doing this at all as you should already have the "related" information. Take a look at your original aggregate:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$nkey",
```

For some reason, you changed this so that it was no longer the `_id` key of this new collection when you wrote it out. Clearly that field is present in all of the documents you sourced from and it simply should have been left as the new primary key.